# Git Bash stuck in master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git-bash

I am new to Rails development and tried to connect to github using gitbash and my shell is stuck in master.
I run windows and cannot run rails commands in this mode. How can i revert to default git bash shell?

[image]

I would start my rails server using "rails s" but now after I messed around with GitHub stuff.
That `master` tag is there and the helper options come up instead!

Comment: Stuck in? you cannot switch branch?

Comment: be more clear. Add some image/code or log which can clearly show what you trying to say.

Comment: Uploaded an image! into mmy questions please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need t he git bash for rails bash scripts, but you don't need the bash for simple git commands.

Unzip [PortableGit-2.8.4-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.4.windows.1/PortableGit-2.8.4-64-bit.7z.exe) anywhere you want, add its bin folder to your `%PATH%` in a regular CMD session, cd to your repo.

Then you can do any git clone/pull/fetch command you want.

In a separate windows, you can call `bash`, and in that bash session, try your `rails` command.